# hello, how can I make it mandatory not to enter the same data in a column in an html form?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

[image]

ex: Must be required when "test2" is entered 2 times

My input

```
<input class="form-control is-invalid"
                            aria-label="Default select example"
                            name="ques_temp{{ i }}" required
                            [(ngModel)]="synColumn[i].tagName"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                            (change)="
                              changeSourceFieldColumn(
                                synColumn[i].tagName,
                                i
                              )
                            "
                          />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a solution that is called *Cross field validation*.

For template driven forms cross field validation is done by a custom directive.
you can find an example in the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-template-driven-forms).